# dataGridView CommandText property has not been initialized in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hi i have written a code in dataGridView for windowsform 
as below

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlCommand CommandText = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM report", con);
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);//its pointing to this line and says ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized.
DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
```

Please let me know what is the issue in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign CommandText to the defined command instead for creating new  `SqlCommand`

```
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM report";
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
```

It is not necessary to define a command to fill datatable using adapter; you can simply do the same by using the following code:

```
  SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM report", con);
  DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
  sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
```

Read more on  [SqlDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Because you never set the `CommandText` property on `sqlCmd`.  Instead, you created a *second* `SqlCommand` object:

```
SqlCommand CommandText = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM report", con);
```

Which you never used.

It sounds like you wanted to set the `CommandText` *property* on the object you *already have*:

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM report";
```